# What kind of language is SQL?

Tags: sql, programming-languages, chomsky-hierarchy

Is SQL a context free language or some other type of language?

Comment: Do you mean is SQL *also* regular? CFG's encompass regular languages. So, they aren't mutually exclusive. To answer your question though, SQL is *not* a regular language.

Comment: Does SQL uses both regular and context free grammar contexts ? 
In that case, being an intersection of both, it is still context free.

Comment: Just to clarify, a language is context-free when it is generated by a context-free grammar. There're SQL context-free grammar definitions online. Just google around and you'll find some. [Here](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html)'s one, for example.

Comment: Does the DELIMITER command throw a wrench in that at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31265136 SQL is not a regular language. The short explanation is that each select query looks like

```
 SELECT x FROM y WHERE z
```

and `y` can be another select query itself, so it cannot be simulated with finite-state machine. As mentioned before, there are some CFGs for SQL standarts in [Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), thereby SQL is **nonregular context free** language.

Answer (score 3):

Any CFG for SQL will do most of the work, but will always be slightly too permissive.

A good example of an SQL CFG comes from antlr: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4#L1982

But at that line (1982), you see that in a `values_clause`, column values are recursively added regardless of how many columns might be specified, or how many values are in another row, which is invalid sql:

```sql
insert into xyz values
  (1, 'hello'),
  (2, 'bye'),
  (3, 'hi', 'uhm...'); -- invalid!
```

Try running it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6gwgcg6qBLKpFbCEPtB6dy/0

This syntax can never be fully encapsulated by a CFG, as it is equivalent to the `{ (a^n)(b^n)(c^n) : n ≥ 1 }` language, which is famously not allowed in CFGs ([but allowed in CSGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples))

You could argue this is a runtime error instead of a parsing error. But you can use the same argument for every language that is interpreted, so it's a bit of a grey area.

Answer (score 2):

@aquinas wrote:

> Do you mean is SQL also regular? CFG's encompass regular languages. So, they aren't mutually exclusive. To answer your question though, SQL is not a regular language.

@MSX wrote:

> Just to clarify, a language is context-free when it is generated by a context-free grammar. There're SQL context-free grammar definitions online. Just google around and you'll find some. [Here's](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html) one, for example.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

Answer (score -2):

Similar in PL/SQL context can be exactly what code it is SQL or PL/SQL
because if we define function keywords as concrete, then if we want to control
which functions can be used, this context must be known

Comment: By me it's when some syntax nonterminal resoult depends on some state (or context), that can be determinated early in parsing process