# Regex put name schema for 'table' in select query syntax

Tags: sql, regex

How can I put with regex, schema name table, for query select?

Query doesn't have fixed size.

Example:

```
select * from t1 union select * from t2
```

Result:

```
select * from schema1.t1 union select * from schema1.t2
```

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is not a regular language, therefore it cannot be parsed by regular expressions. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595394/what-kind-of-languge-is-sql

Comment: Do you really need regex for this? You could just replace "from " to "from schema1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) If you are using it in a code, maybe you can do a search and replace at front end as Luk suggested.

(2) Alternatively, in your current session you can set default schema as `schema1` so your query would work without schema name. But it would depend on your database name.

Like in Oracle you can do

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schema1
```

Now `select * from t1` would effectively mean `select * from schema1.t1`.

You can search `how to set default schema in <your database>` in google and you would get syntax for other databases as well.